# How to allocate 2D array in a function

Tags: c++

I have a function like this:

```
void QuadTree::alloc( Quad***& pQuadsArray ) {
    const int _quadsCount = 100;

    // allocates memory as one chunk of memory
    Quad** _data = new Quad*[_quadsCount * _quadsCount]; 
    pQuadsArray = new Quad**[_quadsCount];
    for( int i = 0; i < _quadsCount; ++i ) {
            pQuadsArray[i] = _data + i * _quadsCount;
    }
}

// calling like this:
Quad*** test = nullptr;
alloc( test );
```

it works well. But this one doesn't and I don't know why:

```
void QuadTree::alloc( Quad**** pQuadsArray ) {
    const int _quadsCount = 100;

    // allocates memory as one chunk of memory
    Quad** _data = new Quad*[_quadsCount * _quadsCount]; 
    *pQuadsArray = new Quad**[_quadsCount];
    for( int i = 0; i < _quadsCount; ++i ) {
            *pQuadsArray[i] = _data + i * _quadsCount; // code crashes here
            // tried *(pQuadsArray[i]) but it didn't help
    }
}

// calling like this:
Quad*** test = nullptr;
alloc( &test );
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: The first thing I have to say is WTF, but http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: @chris 2D array needs '\*\*' + it keeps pointers to Quad objects so it makes it '\*\*\*' + I want the effect outside the function so it is '\*\*\*\*'. Imo your downvote is groundless.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, I was just commenting. You've already found that one can be saved with a reference, though transferring ownership to the caller like that is bad imo. You should just return a `std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Quad>>>` for the caller to use, but also keep in mind that the 2D vector could be replaced with a class encapsulating a 1D one and that you shouldn't have pointers to objects unless you absolutely need them. A `Matrix2D<Quad>` is probably all you need.

Comment: @chris Sorry for judging you. I agree that it doesn't look like a good programming style, but I wanted to avoid any overhead for performance reasons. I am allocating (and deallocating) this array every frame in DirectX app, so I need it as fast as possible. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: That matrix class encapsulating a 1D array and containing just objects is probably as fast as you need. If you really want to, do a benchmark on the options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an operator precedence problem - change:

```
        *pQuadsArray[i] = _data + i * _quadsCount; // code crashes here
```

to:

```
        (*pQuadsArray)[i] = _data + i * _quadsCount;
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to remove the question because of the groundless (imo) -1 for '****'. But I don't want you to lose the points for your help, thanks.

Comment: Don't worry about the odd -1 - it happens for various reasons and is not always justified, but if you have more +1s than -1s then I wouldn't worry about it.